# TYPO3: re-define altLabels in TCEFORM for layout with multisite

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I use EXT:T3sBootstrap and define comprehensible voices for the layouts the editors may select ... this works fine with the following code:

***ext_localconf.php :***

```
# Set TCEFORM features 
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:myExt/Configuration/PageTSConfig/TCEForm.ts">');
```

***Configuration/PageTSConfig/TCEForm.ts :***

```
TCEFORM {
    tt_content {
        layout {
            addItems {
                4 = special box
                100 = extra
            }
            altLabels {
                0 = Default
                1 = image shadow
                2 = line shadow
                3 = line shadow inv
            }
            disableNoMatchingValueElement = 1
        }
    }
}
```

in my second site I want to be able to re-define these labels with comprehensible voices but, although the static template of the first site is not included, it takes this configuration and does not use the one I just defined in the new myExt ...

Comment: I would like to help, but somehow it is not clear what happens. Could you please extend your question with the following information:
- Make an example pls with the two site. Like: 
         -Site1:  In the page properties is the PageTS Template selected
         -Site2:  .... (and so on)
- Pls write it down what is the expected and what is the current result

The problem, that I don't understand your last lines. What is "this configurtion" and what exactly "new myExt" mean. Is there two of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Page) TSconfig is loaded independent from the TypoScript static templates. The way you currently load the TSconfig into TYPO3, it will be used for all websites in this TYPO3 instance. So, the TSconfig from your second site is simply overwritten by your first configuration shown above.

Since TYPO3 v7, you can use [`registerPageTSConfigFile`](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html#a90dd25a333c9701c930cadea9adbbc8b) to add TSconfig settings as needed into your different page trees and websites:

**your_extension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerPageTSConfigFile(
    'your_extension',
    'Configuration/PageTSConfig/TCEForm.ts',
    'My TCEform config including custom altLabels'
);
```

This enables you to select the TSconfig in the page properties, where it will apply for all subpages.

You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/sebkln/basetemplate8/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php).

Comment: Thank you sebkln, that answer was spot-on !!